# Prometheus Pushgetway get data, data coverage appears

Tags: bash, prometheus

```
cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/pushgetway/instance/test_instance
http_s_attack_type{hostname="test1",scheme="http",src_ip="192.168.33.86",dst_ip="192.168.33.85",port="15555"} 44
http_s_attack_type{hostname="other",scheme="tcp",src_ip="1.2.3.4",dst_ip="192.168.33.85",port="15557"} 123
EOF
```

Change data and write again：

```
cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/pushgetway/instance/test_instance
http_s_attack_type{hostname="test2",scheme="http",src_ip="192.168.33.86",dst_ip="192.168.33.85",port="15555"} 55
http_s_attack_type{hostname="other3",scheme="tcp",src_ip="1.2.3.4",dst_ip="192.168.33.85",port="15557"} 14
EOF
```

View the data on localhost:9091 becomes the last write data, the data written for the first time is overwritten。

Is there a problem with my operation? Please tell me how to continuously introduce new data without being overwritten or replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working exactly as designed. The pushgateway is meant to hold the results of batch jobs when they exit, so on the next run the results will replace the previous run.

It sounds like you're trying to do event logging. Prometheus is not a suitable tool for that use case, you might want to consider something like the ELK stack instead.

Comment: The pushgetway isn't a tool for changing prometheus from pull to push mode? If i use the counter/gauge/histogram/summary type function when sending data, is it possible to preserve the effect?

Comment: Under the same metrics_name, adding or deleting labels will form a new time series. Why does pushgetway result in overwriting? How do I change the label to generate a new time series?